# How to set the fully qualified hostname on CentOS 7.0?

Tags: centos, hostname, domain

How do I set the fully qualified hostname on CentOS 7.0?

I have seen a few posts online for example using:

```
$ sudo hostnamectl set-hostname nodename.domainname
```

However, running domainname returns nothing:

```
$ domainname
(none)
```

Also:

```
$ hostname
nodename.domainname
```

However,

```
$ hostname -f
hostname: Name or service not known
$ hostname -d
hostname: Name or service not known
```

Some debug output:

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
nodename.domainname

$ grep ^hosts /etc/nsswitch.conf
hosts:      files dns
```

Answer (score 40, accepted):

To set the **hostname** *do* use `hostnamectl`, but only with the hostname, like this:

```
hostnamectl set-hostname nodename
```

To set the **(DNS) domainname** edit `/etc/hosts` file and ensure that:

1. There is a line `<machine's primary, non-loopback IP address> <hostname>.<domainname> <hostname>` there
2. There are NO other lines with `<some IP> <hostname>`, and this includes lines with `127.0.0.1` and `::1` (IPv6) addresses.

Note that unless you’re using NIS, `(none)` is the correct output when running the `domainname` command.

To check if your DNS domainname is set correctly use `dnsdomainname` command and check output of `hostname` vs `hostname -f` (FQDN).

### NIS vs. DNS domain

This issue confused me when I first came across it. It seems that the `domainname` command predates the popularity of the Internet. Instead of the DNS domain name, it shows or sets the system’s [**NIS (Network Information Service)**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_Information_Service) aka YP (Yellow Pages) domain name (a group of computers which have services provided by a master NIS server).  This command simply displays the name returned by the `getdomainname(2)` standard library function. (`nisdomainname` and `ypdomainname` are alternative names for this command.)

### Display the FQDN or DNS domain name

To check the **DNS** (Internet) domain name, you should run the `dnsdomainname` command or `hostname` with the `-d, --domain` options. (Note that the `dnsdomainname` command  can’t be used to set the DNS domain name  – it’s only used to display it.)

To display the **FQDN (Fully Qualified Domain Name)** of the system, run `hostname` with the `-f, --fqdn, --long` options (likewise, this command can’t be used to set the domain name part).

The above commands use the system’s resolver (implemented by the `gethostbyname(3)` function from the standard library, as specified by POSIX) to determine the DNS domain name and the FQDN.

### Name Resolution

In modern operating systems such as RHEL 7, the `hosts` entry in `/etc/nsswitch.conf` is used for resolving host names. In your CentOS 7 machine, this line is configured as (default for CentOS 7):

```
hosts:      files dns
```

This means that when when the resolver functions look up hostnames or IP address, they first check for an entry in the `/etc/hosts` *file* and next try the *DNS server(s)* which are listed in `/etc/resolv.conf`.

When running `hostname -f` to obtain the FQDN of a host, the resolver functions try to get the FQDN for the system’s hostname. If the host is not listed in the `/etc/hosts` file or by the relevant DNS server, the attempt fails and `hostname` reports that `Name or service not known`.

When `hostname -d` is run to obtain the domain name, the same operations are carried out, and the domain name part is determined by stripping the hostname part and the first dot from the FQDN.

### Configure the domain name

1. Update the relevant DNS name server

   In my case, I had already added an entry for my new CentOS 7 machine in the DNS server for my local LAN so when the FQDN wasn’t found in the `/etc/hosts` file when I ran `hostname` with the `-d` or `-f` option, the local DNS services were able to fully resolve the FQDN for my new hostname.
2. Use the `/etc/hosts` file

   If the DNS server haven’t been configured, the fully qualified domain name can be specified in the `/etc/hosts` file. The most common way to do this is to specify the primary IP address of the system followed by its FQDN and its short hostname. E.g.,

   ```
    172.22.0.9  nodename.domainname nodename
   ```

#### Excerpt from [`hostname` man page](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/hostname/hostname.1.en.html#THE_FQDN)

> You cannot change the FQDN with `hostname` or `dnsdomainname`.
>
> The recommended method of setting the FQDN is to make the hostname be
> an alias for the fully qualified name using `/etc/hosts,` DNS, or
> NIS. For example, if the hostname was "ursula", one might have a line
> in `/etc/hosts` which reads:
>
> ```
> 127.0.1.1    ursula.example.com ursula
> ```
>
> Technically: The FQDN is the name getaddrinfo(3) returns for the host
> name returned by gethostname(2). The DNS domain name is the part
> after the first dot.
>
> Therefore it depends on the configuration of the resolver (usually in
> `/etc/host.conf`) how you can change it. Usually the hosts file is
> parsed before DNS or NIS, so it is most common to change the FQDN in
> `/etc/hosts`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I've updated the question - unfortunately the `hostname -f` command doesn't work on my CentOS vm.

Comment: @SHC Can you edit your question to also include the contents of `/etc/hostname` and the output of `grep ^hosts: /etc/nsswitch.conf`? I don't know much about Network Manager but I also noticed that my `/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf` contains a line in its `[keyfile]` section: `hostname=<nodename>`.

Comment: @SHC I've since been researching the issue, and have radically revised my answer; it should now address your question more comprehensively.

Comment: The lede to this answer is inconsistent with the body.  `hostnamectl set-hostname nodename.domainname` does *not* set the DNS domain name (and it's not that it sets the NIS domain name either).

Comment: @sourcejedi I don't have time at the moment but I'll try to clarify my answer when I get the chance.

Comment: I tried to clarify it for you, @AnthonyGeoghegan. I hope that my change gets accepted, it changes the first section (before "NIS vs. DNS domain") quite a lot. But thanks for the great explanation part of your answer! :)

Comment: @GregDubicki I 've accepted your edit but I'm not sure what you mean in the 2nd point, *There are NO other lines with " ", and this includes lines with 127.0.0.1 and ::1 (IPv6) addresses*.

Comment: Stack's formatting has hidden part of my change there. I have just send a fix. Thanks @AnthonyGeoghegan !

Comment: I agree, yet a lot of guides claim that the FQDN should also be set as the hostname on CentOS/EL. Such as: hostnamectl set-hostname nodename.domainname - 

"Recommended naming practices: A host name can be a free-form string of up to 64 characters in length. However, Red Hat recommends that both static and transient names match the fully-qualified domain name (FQDN) used for the machine in DNS, such as host.example.com." https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/7/html/migration_planning_guide/sect-red_hat_enterprise_linux-migration_planning_guide-networking

Answer (score 2):

On Centos7 using nmtui to set the hostname and providing nodename.domainname / FQDN format is giving consistent results. hostname [d/f/s] all provide correct expected results. It is not stored in /etc/resolv.conf OR /etc/hosts. But the FQDN is written to /etc/hostname as a single line entry.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the /etc/hostname file contained the FQDN instead of the hostname (e.g., hostname instead of hostname.example.com). Once I removed the domain from the hostname in /etc/hostname the 'hostname -f' command worked normally.

I think this was introduced as I installed the CentOS 7 VM. I should have entered just the hostname, not the fully qualified domain name.

Answer (score 0):

Similar issue as OP (RHEL7), and solved it by removing a trailing space from short hostname listed in the `/etc/hostname` file.  Followed by `systemctl restart systemd-hostnamed`.  Now showing FQDN with `hostname -f` command.