# $HOSTNAME mismatch

Tags: rhel, hostname

There are two different version of hostname on my system. This is a problem when trying to use wget against $HOSTNAME, which differs from what is expected.

```
[user@box ~]# wget https://$HOSTNAME/login.php
--2021-08-22 23:25:07--  https://superserver/login.php
Resolving superserver (superserver)... 11.22.33.44
Connecting to superserver (superserver)|11.22.33.44|:443... connected.
The certificate's owner does not match hostname ‘superserver’
[user@box ~]# echo $HOSTNAME
superserver
[user@box ~]# cat /proc/sys/kernel/hostname 
superserver.some.domain.com
[user@box ~]# 
[user@box ~]# hostname 
superserver.some.domain.com
[user@box ~]#
```

How do I update my system such that `$HOSTNAME` reflects what is in `/proc/sys/kernel/hostname`, and what appears when I issue `hostname`?

Or do I simply add a line in /etc/hosts?

Comment: Did you change the hostname *after* you started the shell session where you executed these commands?

Comment: Related: [unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239920](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/239920)

Comment: Try editing `/etc/hosts`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hostnamectl set-hostname superserver.some.domain.com
systemctl reboot now
```